# Querydsl: BooleanExpression generating unexpected parenthesis

Tags: java, querydsl

I am using querydsl lib to generate a complex expression-
The output that I intent is -

**e1 = 1 || (e2 = 2 && e3 = 3)**

But the query that is generated is-
**e1 = 1 || e2 = 2 && e3 = 3**

Here is the code:

```
    Predicate exp1 = Expressions.predicate(Ops.EQ,
            Expressions.path(String.class, "e1"),
            Expressions.path(Object.class, "1"));
    Predicate exp2 = Expressions.predicate(Ops.EQ,
            Expressions.path(String.class, "e2"),
            Expressions.path(Object.class, "2"));
    Predicate exp3 = Expressions.predicate(Ops.EQ,
            Expressions.path(String.class, "e3"),
            Expressions.path(Object.class, "3"));

    BooleanBuilder builder = new BooleanBuilder(exp1);
    BooleanBuilder builder2 = new BooleanBuilder(exp2);
    builder2.and(exp3);
    builder.or(builder2);
```

The weird thing is that, if i reverse the 'and' and 'or' operators in my code, I am getting correct parenthesis-
e1 = 1 && (e2 = 2 || e3 = 3)

Need some help with this. Thanks

Comment: `e1 = 1 || (e2 = 2 && e3 = 3)` and `e1 = 1 || e2 = 2 && e3 = 3` are equivalent, while `e1 = 1 && (e2 = 2 || e3 = 3)` and `e1 = 1 && e2 = 2 || e3 = 3` are not

Comment: @alfasin, just checked the operator precedence for sql. in a nutshell, the order of priority is parenthesis-> and-> or. 
So you are right about the 2 exp being equivalent.

I suppose querydsl only provides parenthesis if absolutely necessary.